# How to add a weather app in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am attempting to add weather data on our group sharepoint site 2013, which would be the best way to get this done, I am also looking to adding more than 1 location, if you could provide me step by step how to's that would be fantastic,. Thank you for your time and attention in reference to this matter.

Thank you so much Jain for taking the time out to respond. How would I add it to the SP site ( api)? Adding a script app, content editor, etc, any direction to you can provide will be very helpful. Tks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a weather API from AccueWeather or OpenWeatherMap. For SP2013, you can create a rest code to geolocate and then call the corresponding weather API to get data. For details : https://openweathermap.org/current might help you.

Comment: Thank you so much Jain for taking the time out to respond. How would I add it to the SP site? Adding a script app, content editor, etc, any direction to you can provide will be very helpful. Tks again

Comment: I prefer the content editor way. I suggest to do some reading on basic modules using REST API. I have brought you towards the water and you need to drink it.